# Tool to migrate TFS repository to SVN/GIT/HG

Tags: version-control, tfs

Is it possible to migrate the source from a TFS repository to to one of the open version control systems while preserving history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import TFS History into Mercurial (hg)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046261/import-tfs-history-into-mercurial-hg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier discussion
[Import TFS History into Mercurial (hg)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046261/import-tfs-history-into-mercurial-hg)